# File download using selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium for testing a system.
I have to download a text file. In order to download it directly I've created a Firefox profile which should avoid the `Save / cancel` dialog... butthe dialog is still coming.

My code is as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\tmp");
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain");
driver.findElement(By.id("link-download")).click();
```

I cannot find why the dialog is still opened.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if this might be browser-version dependent.  Or something like such? Maybe an older vs. of firefox?

Comment: Does your browser ever open?

Comment: I'm guessing its the last preference you are setting.  Are you sure that `text/plain` is the MIME type of the download?

Comment: Mmmmm. you are right. The mime type is <code>application/octet-stream</code>. Thanks Mrti for pointing this! But changing it to this mime type didn't change anything...

Comment: @Adel: No, it is the last version of Firefox.

Comment: @sircapsalot: The browser is opening and when the download comes the dialog is open. This is what should not happen... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it.

The Firefox profile has to be passed as a parameter when creating the driver as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\tmp");
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");

    setDriver(TestBench.createDriver(new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile)));
```

I wass creating the driver without parameters. Now it is working.

Comment: check this post http://qaautomationworld.blogspot.in/2014/02/file-downlaoding-using-selenium.html

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I need another Preference to make it working, it's also interesting to have Javascript Enabled.

```
File downloadDir = new File(DOWNLOAD_PATH);
FirefoxProfile fProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
fProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
fProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir.getAbsolutePath());
fProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
fProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
fProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fProfile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Download All Files (Eg: .xls, .csv, .pdf)

I also face same problem in my application:

I got solution using Robot in java

following code i write to download all file

```
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //create robot object
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //Click Down Arrow Key to select "Save File" Radio Button
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    // Click 3 times Tab to take focus on "OK" Button
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //Click "Enter" Button to download file
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                    System.out.println("Robot work Complete");
```